# Why is concat randomly duplicating output in this XSLT transformation?

Tags: java, xslt, concatenation, xalan

I am using XSLT to transform HTML to XSL-FO.  The fact that we are transforming from HTML to XSL-FO is probably irrelevant to answering this question.

For several of my values which use `concat` for font size and height, the output of `concat` is randomly duplicated for a single call.

**Example**: where the value of `$lineheight-td` is `13` for the following code:

```
<fo:block line-height="{concat($lineheight-td, 'pt')}">
```

this is the expected correct output that I usually receive:

```
<fo:block line-height="13pt">
```

this is incorrect output that I receive ~1% of the time:

```
<fo:block line-height="13pt13pt">
```

this is incorrect output that I receive < 1% of the time:

```
<fo:block line-height="13pt&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;">
```

(note how unexpected output is 4 characters (`'1'`, `'3'`, `'p'`, `'t'`) and the unexpected `'&#0;'` is produced 4 times).

These duplicate outputs generate from the `concat` call in different places from the same input HTML file on different iterations.

My current workaround is to re-transform if we get a bad output; so far this solves the problem, and proves this isn't data-related, but the duplicate output shouldn't be happening in the first place.  I'm running under a multi-threaded Java environment, but I'm using a new `Transformer` for each individual transformation call, from a shared `Template` initialized one time at application start-up.

**Why is this happening with concat, and how do I fix it?**

The application uses an older Xalan library (2.7.0).  I'm going to look into Xalan bugs and upgrading to Xalan 2.7.1 or higher.

**Environment:**

```
JBoss 7.2.0
JRE 1.7.0_45
xalan-2.7.0
xml-apis-1.3.04
xml-apis-ext-1.3.04
```

**Java code:**

```
String inputData = ...; // OUR HTML

Templates template = (Templates)templatesMap.get("HTML2FO");
Transformer transformer = template.newTransformer();
StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(data));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(streamSource, new StreamResult(writer));

String outputData = writer.toString();  // OUR FO
```

Comment: Try using Apache Xerces instead of the JDK version of Xerces as your XML parser. There's a long-standing bug in the JDK version whereby it occasionally corrupts attribute values. I don't know whether a corruption of an input attribute value could account for the symptoms you are seeing, but it is worth trying.

Comment: I think the latest version is 2.11.0, and you should put it in the "endorsed" directory. If that doesn't mean anything to you search for "Xerces endorsed directory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The application uses an older Xalan library (2.7.0).  **I'm going to look into Xalan bugs and upgrading to Xalan 2.7.1 or higher.**

Xalan version release notes only list bug numbers without descriptions, and at some point after releasing Xalan 2.7.1, Xalan development switched to a different bug tracker.  The information about their old, "fixed" bugs has disappeared.

Having nothing to "prove" there was a problem with any given library, **I ended up updating all XML- and Transformation-related JAR files to the following versions:**

```
JAR FILE NAME           VERSION
serializer.jar          2.7.2
xalan.jar               2.7.2
xerxesImpl.jar          2.11.0
xml-apis.jar            1.4.01
xml-apis-ext.jar        1.4.01
```

For ~8,000 transformations using the original XML libraries, I experienced a 99% success rate; the failed files successfully re-processed on a second iteration, which indicates the issue was not with my data.

For ~11,500 transformations using the updated XML libraries, I experienced a 100% success rate.

I'll continue to test, but **I can conclude that updating all of the libraries seems to have solved the problem.**

Comment: Do you feel it may have been a thread safety issue with one of the earlier versions of one of those libraries?

Comment: @kjhughes - no; I recently refactored the code to be multi-threaded in this area, and to break out our steps to catch problems like this one.  The old, single-threaded system just failed it (or pushed through to another step with a potentially failing file) and retried it from the beginning. We had these errors occasionally, but could never track them down. I'm pretty sure it was a problem with the library code setting the attribute values.